# How do I copy an object without copying the weights?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I have a man I am making clothes for.  when I copy his upper body to build a shirt the weight painting for the armature gets copied along with the object but I don't want it to and I can't seem to erase all the weight painting from the copied object.  I was wondering if I could either copy object without weights somehow, or remove all weights from a object somehow.  Either one would work, thanks!

Comment: You can delete that vertex group that was added when you created that vertex weights

Comment: Hey Isak, did Mr Zak's solution help?

Comment: I'm not seeing a new vertex group.  I duplicate the object, then separate it so it is it's own mesh.  The problem is it still has all the weights that the object it came from had.  I'm not seeing that it created a new vertex group, but I could be wrong, I'm relatively new to Blender.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer. I had to remove the armature modifier from the mesh. I found that out here, http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-235499.html